# Input value not showing in the react textbox

Tags: reactjs

I am making a sign up component in which i have 4 fields:

1. email
2. password
3. display name
4. confirm password

---

When I update the value by using `onChange` function on my *input fields*, **email** and **password** of the *input fields* are working, and **display name** and **confirm password** not showing the text.

---

I dont understand why is it happening?

````
                                  **SignUp.jsx**
```



     class SignUp extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);

                this.state={
                    displayName:'',
                    email:'',
                    password:'',
                    confirmPassword:''
                }
            }

           handleChange = (event)=>{
                const { name, value } = event.target;
                this.setState({ [name]: value }, ()=>console.log(`name:${name} and value:${value} and target${event.target}`));
            }

            render(){
                const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
                return(
                    <>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <FormInput handleChange={this.handleChange} name="email" type="email" label="email" value={email} required/>

                        <FormInput handleChange={this.handleChange} name="password" type="password" label="password" value={password}/>

                        <FormInput handleChange={this.handleChange} name="display-name" type="text" label="display name" value={displayName} required/>

                        <FormInput handleChange={[see the following images][1]this.handleChange} name="confirm-password" type="password" label="confirm password" value={confirmPassword}/>

                    <Button type="submit" value="Sign Up" input_class="signup-button"/>               
                </form>
                </>
            );
        }
    }

```

                              **FormInput.jsx**

```

    const FormInput = ({handleChange, label, ...otherFormFields}) => (
        <div className="group">
            {label?
                (<label className={`${otherFormFields.value.length? 'shrink' : ''} form-input-label`}>
                {label.toUpperCase()}
                </label>) 
                : null
            }
            <div>
                <input className="form-input" onChange={handleChange} {...otherFormFields}></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

    export default FormInput;

```
when i enter the value in email text field
```
 **name:email and value:q
 name:email and value:qu
 name:email and value:que
 name:email and value:quer
 name:email and value:query
 name:email and value:query@
 name:email and value:query@g
 name:email and value:query@gm
 name:email and value:query@gma
 name:email and value:query@gmai
 name:email and value:query@gmail
 name:email and value:query@gmail.
 name:email and value:query@gmail.c
 name:email and value:query@gmail.co
 name:email and value:query@gmail.com**
```
when i enter the value in password text field
```
 **name:password and value:h
 name:password and value:he
 name:password and value:hel
 name:password and value:hell
 name:password and value:hello**
```

but when i enter the value in confirm password or display name
```
**name:display-name and value:q
name:display-name and value:w
name:display-name and value:e
name:display-name and value:r
name:display-name and value:t
name:display-name and value:y**
```
why is it overriding the value every time, and the text box remains empty.


  [IMAGE]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxFVg.png
````

Comment: P.D. React doesn't handle names like `some-thing` instead use `someThing` (camelCase)

Answer (score 0):

in `state` you have `displayName` and `confirmPassword`, change `FormInput` names to match.

```
<FormInput handleChange={this.handleChange} name="displayName" type="text" label="display name" value={displayName} required/>

<FormInput handleChange={[see the following images][1]this.handleChange} name="confirmPassword" type="password" label="confirm password" value={confirmPassword} />
```

Answer (score 0):

See working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-golick-43k27

For your `state` to update dynamically and coordinate with your `handleChange` method, you should provide `names` to your inputs that match directly with a key in the `state` object. Hence, `displayName` is not the same as `display-name` and `confirm-password` does not equal `confirmPassword`.

```
      <FormInput
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        name="displayName"
        type="text"
        label="display name"
        value={displayName}
        required
      />
      <FormInput
        name="confirmPassword"
        type="password"
        label="confirm password"
        value={confirmPassword}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
```

Just take a look at the handleChange function you defined:

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
```

This essentially says, take the `name` property from the element that is creating this event, and use that `name` to find the matching `key` in our component `state`. Once found, update the `key` with the `value` from this element.

Answer (score 0):

There are 'displayName' and 'confirmPassword' properties in the local state, but the name attribute of FormInput displayName is 'display-name', same for 'confirm-password'.

So the event.target.name are 'display-name' and 'confirm-password' in handleChange method.

Either change name attribute to match state properties or vice-versa.

I would recommend you to watch state altering in React DevTools where you would see the new state properties ('display-name' and 'confirm-password') when you typed, so you would guess it.

Answer (score -1):

change value by defaultValue

```
<FormInput handleChange={this.handleChange} name="email" type="email" label="email" defaultValue={email} required/>
```

Comment: Can't edit now... So.. Changing value by default value will not fix the problem, that is wrong `names` in `name` fields on `FormInput`.